# WordPress Div Align Right Youtube Not Working

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out a way to embed my Youtube code into WordPress, but keep it to the right of the screen, I assume floating, in order to have the text wrap around it.

```
[youtube height="208" width="350"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNJUL92y9wo[/youtube]
```

I've tried using:

```
<div style="float:left; padding:10px;">[youtube height="208" width="350"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNJUL92y9wo[/youtube]</div>
```

But whenever I use a "style" tag, it just disappears on the page and goes invisible.

I appreciate any help I can get. I hope I've been specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using the [embed] tags instead of the YouTube ones:

```
<div style="float:right; padding:10px;">
    [embed height="208" width="350"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNJUL92y9wo[/embed]    
</div>
```

Comment: For whatever reason, whenever that "style" tag is added, the entire thing disappears.

Comment: Have you tried adding a class to the div instead and just putting the styles into the stylesheet?